how is typing a function with list[TypeVar bound to MotherClass] different from typing directly with list[MotherClass]?
I wrote a small utilitarian function to convert a list of class instances to a list of dictionaries. The implementation is the following:
from pydantic import RootModel, BaseModel

def convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(pydantic_sequence):
    return RootModel(pydantic_sequence).model_dump()

# For the sake of the example
class MyModel(BaseModel): ...

However, I figured that this function accepts both list of pydantic models (that are children of BaseModel) or tuple of pydantic models. I tried to write overloads of this function like this:
@overload
def convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(
    pydantic_list: list[BaseModel],
) -> list[dict]: ...


@overload
def convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(
    pydantic_list: tuple[BaseModel],
) -> tuple[dict]: ...

but I got a mypy error when I was passing a list of models
var = list[MyModel(), MyModel()]
convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(var)
# Argument 1 to "convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list" has incompatible type
# "list[MyModel]"; expected "list[BaseModel]".

After reading some documentation about invariance, covariance, etc., I figured that the solution was lying in TypeVars. The following works:
T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)

@overload
def convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(pydantic_list: list[T]) -> list[dict]: ...

@overload
def convert_pydantic_list_to_dict_list(pydantic_list: tuple[T]) -> tuple[dict]: ...

I don't fully understand why bounding a typevar to BaseModel (saying that it can be BaseModel or any of its sub class) then typing the function with list[T], is different from directly typing the function with list[BaseModel].
In both case the list is invariant, and the type its elements can have are sub type of BaseModel, isn't it? Is it because of contravariance in callable arguments?
Thank you for your time.

list[BaseModel] means a list of BaseModels, not subclasses nor super, due to invariance. list[T] with T bounded to BaseModel means a list of some type that is a subtype of BaseModel, but that needs to be inferred at call site.

Possible duplicates: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "List[Union[str, int]]"), mypy: creating a type that accepts list of instances of subclasses and many others.

Thanks you @inSync. I think I got it. The second subject might be a duplicate indeed. I did not think about searching for the mypy error directly.

@InSync I have a counter example of what you ve just said
class Mom: ...


class Child(Mom): ...


def allo(person: Mom): ...


allo(Mom())
allo(Child())

Will be okay for numpy

That's not a counterexample: parameters are contravariant, your example is the essence of LSP. However, list[Child] is not a subtype of list[Parent], because the latter allows .append(Parent()) and the former forbids that - so list is invariant in type parameter due to mutability. Use collections.abc.{Container, Iterable,Sequence} for some restricted versions, all of them are immutable.

than you so much @STerliakov! It is a really hard concept to grasp but you explain it very well. Have a nice day
